# How can I import the configuration on a different site?

Tags: 8, configuration

I have this error when I try to import the config of an another site:

> The staged configuration cannot be imported, because it originates
>   from a different site than this site. You can only synchronize
>   configuration between cloned instances of this site.

I have 10 customers, and I need to sync my site configuration with 10 different websites.
The site UUID is a problem for sharing a configuration with a different website. Is there a solution?

Comment: Another nice answer here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/152584/39617

Comment: One way to do it is to import the config as part of a clean install. You can select the config as a profile similar to default or minimal.

Comment: One way to do this is to add $settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../config/sync'; in your settings somewhere.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Using Drupal Console

You can override your current site's UUID with the value present in the configuration you want to import.

You can achieve this with Drupal Console by overriding the *uuid* key for *system.site*.

```bash
drupal config:override
```

Then enter *system.site* for the configuration name, *uuid* for the configuration, and the UUID value, when prompted for each of them.

Answer (score 99):

Youu can get the UUID with `drush config-get "system.site" uuid`.
You can change it with `drush config-set "system.site" uuid [uuid]`.

Comment: I needed to create a dev environment for a site that I have no access to the server. I found the uuid in the configuration export file. It is in the file system.site.yml.

Comment: And then before finally `drush -y cim` you may additionally `drush -y entity:delete shortcut_set` when running into *The import failed due to the following reasons:
  Entities exist of type <em class="placeholder">Shortcut link</em> and <em c
  lass="placeholder">Shortcut set</em> <em class="placeholder">Default</em>.
  These entities need to be deleted before importing.*

Comment: If you need a uuid without the keys as I do for scripting: 

drush config-get "system.site" uuid --format

Comment: My site uuid is null :|. Don't know how that's possible...

Comment: And it doesn't work, try without the double quotes.

Comment: The import failed due to the following reasons:                 
  Site UUID in source storage does not match the target storage.

Comment: Err, why are we setting the same value that we are getting?

Comment: @kopeboy this is my function to set uuid, I hope it helps. 

luuid () {
 loc=$(find config/ -name system.site.yml)
 uuid=$(awk '/uuid/ {print $2}' < $loc)
 lando drush -y cset system.site uuid $uuid
}

Answer (score 26):

The Configuration Management only allow sync configuration between same site or project to avoid issues importing configuration from site a.com to b.com, to accomplish this validation Drupal 8 generate a [UUID](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid) for each site.

You cat get your current site UUID executing the following command:

```
drush cget system.site
```

The command above we will have a similar output to next listing:

```
uuid: 236fa77c-d83e-42de-8a03-03c574c00160
name: Drupal 8
mail: user@example.com
slogan: ''
page:
  403: ''
  404: ''
  front: node
admin_compact_mode: false
weight_select_max: 100
langcode: en
```

The config import has a different UUID, you can confirm the UUID with the following command

```
cat sites/default/config/staging/system.site.yml
```

For that reason you need to change the value of Site UUID using the following Drush command:

```
drush cedit system.site
```

The command above enable you to use your favorite text editor to set the same UUID present in staging config files.

```
cat sites/default/config/staging/system.site.yml
```

After change the UUID and change the permissions, if you visit again the page example.com/admin/config/development/configuration you will see all changes, deletions, renames, and additions.

source: http://enzolutions.com/articles/2014/08/27/understanding-configuration-management-in-drupal-8/

Comment: Correct, but keep in mind that changing the site UUID without changing any others means that drupal will treat every field/node type/view/... that has a different UUID as a different thing and will first delete the old and then re-create it again, which will essentially delete all your content.

Comment: Ok thank you, but it's not user-friendly for a user without a dedicated server and linux knowledge, a solution exist for basic/beginner users (without ssh and command lines, only a ftp server) please ? Drush need command lines and it's not user-friendly for my customers.

Comment: What's happen exactly if I change the site UUID of an existing Drupal website (fresh install) to match the exported configuration (with `drush config-set system.site uuid "abcdef-..."`) ?

Comment: One-line command to copy update site UUID.
`drush -y cset system.site uuid $(cat /path/to/config/system.site.yml | awk '/uuid/ { print $2 }')`

Comment: if use have any problem using drush, kindly use devel module to get the current site UUID,
 \Drupal::config('system.site')->set('uuid', $this->siteUuid)->save();

Answer (score 11):

**You can get the site UUID without access to the site or database.**

If you don't have access to the original site/database, you can still sync from provided config files. The config will contain your site's UUID, so you need to set that first.

1. Find your config/sync directory:
   If it's moved, you can find where it was set in `settings.php`. Look for:
   `$config_directories['sync']`, which will list the path.
2. Go to that config path, and look for the file: `system.site.yml`
   In that file, look for `uuid: 86b376c5-385e-4d13-bf00-e5e5443540e3` (you will have a different value, obviously). Copy that value.
3. In drush, set your site to the same site uuid that we just discovered:
   `drush cset system.site uuid 86b376c5-385e-4d13-bf00-e5e5443540e3`
4. Sync the config using drush
   `drush cim -y`
5. If you get errors, *read them*.
   I had:

   - a missing module (which I had to download and enable)
   - content from the shortcuts module, which I had to delete first, at:
   - admin > config > User Interfact > Shortcuts

Once I did that, I reran the cim, and everything worked like a charm!

I had installed a local D8 instance before trying to restore from the provided config.

Answer (score 6):

You can change the UUID for the destination site using drush cset and drush cget.

First get the source UUID:

```
$ cd ~/Sites/sourcesite <-- your drupal site root
$ drush cget system.site uuid
This will return something like:
'system.site:uuid': 86b376c5-385e-4d13-bf00-e5e5443540e3
```

Replace the destination UUID

```
cd ~/Sites/destinationsite <-- your drupal site root
$ drush cset system.site uuid 86b376c5-385e-4d13-bf00-e5e5443540e3
```

Now you can:

1. Navigate to the destination site in your browser at admin/config/development/configuration/full/import
2. select the configuration archive and select upload
3. You will see a list of all the configuration items
4. Scroll down to the bottom and click the import all button

Answer (score 2):

### How to automate the setting of the system.site uuid before config import

For people getting tired of doing this all over again. I finally got a fix on how to do this automatically. You would have to add a pre-command for config:import with drush to set the uuid. Read all about it here: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/fixing-systemsite-uuid-config-import-problem-drupal-8

Comment: tryed that but get an class Drupal not found error. `'Error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal' not found in /var/www/html/drush/Commands/CustomCommands.php:12
` Fürther I can see a  new command drush set:uuid which isn't called befor the drush cim

Answer (score 2):

Using the solution given by [apaderno](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/apaderno), I was able to import my config from another site which is an easy way to copy content types from a project to another for instance.

1. Copy UUID from another site.
   You can find it in system.site.yml or get it with

   `drush config-get "system.site" uuid`
2. Change the UUID with

   `drush config-set "system.site" uuid [uuid]`

Of course troubles are to be expected if you try this on sites using different versions of Drupal.

If anyone think this is a bad idea, please let me know why.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the instructions in Gucho Ca's answer, and still have the problem, be sure to check that you have write permissions in your sync config directory. It will give you this same error message, even if your uuids are the same, but your sytem doesn't have write permissions.

A good way to check is to click on the Import Tab of the Synchronize section. If you don't have the correct file permissions it will tell you there.

Answer (score 0):

The Above answers used to work for me until Drupal 9.2.3, but they are no longer working on Drupal 9.2.4 and Drush 10.6.0.

I was able to fix this issue by applying the patch given in ["Site UUID in source storage does not match the target storage." when importing a config with empty system.site UUID](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3047392).

Comment: Please don't copy-paste the same answer to different questions. It's also not clear in which way a patch for ["Site UUID in source storage does not match the target storage." when importing a config with empty system.site UUID](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3047392) which is expressly for empty system UUIDs can help the user who asked this question. The issue has been opened for Drupal 8.9.x, and it hasn't been yet resolved; the same problem is present in Drupal 9.2.x and Drupal 9.3.x.