# What are cloned sites in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, configuration

When trying to export my site configurations from one Drupal 8 site to other I keep getting the following error

> The staged configuration cannot be imported, because it originates
>   from a different site than this site. You can only synchronize
>   configuration between cloned instances of this site.

So in this context what are cloned sites? How can I override this error to import the configurations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cloned site means that you copied the database instead of installing twice from scratch.

Drupal identifies two different sites as cloned sites by checking their `uuid`. If the uuids match, then it will assume that the sites are cloned instances.

Faulty configuration imports can lead to broken sites which we may not be able to restore. Hence to avoid this situation as discussed on https://www.drupal.org/node/2133325 a safety mechanism was introduced. And that mechanism was having a `uuid` for each Drupal site.

So if you know what you are doing and you are sure that you need to import the configurations, you can use the `drush cget system.site` command on source site and you can use `drush cedit system.site` on target website to change the uuid to that from the source.

Comment: In a single sentence, cloned usually simply means that you copied the database instead of installing twice from scratch.

Comment: I installed my site from scratch and did'nt copied the database, why have i this error message?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in cloned sites also when I add to .gitignore and remove from git cache the exported /config/sync/system.site.yml.