# Export and import configuration settings and content

Tags: 8, features, configuration

I have created two sites. They have the same modules and themes available, however I want them to be complete clones of each other without doing a manual database export and import.

I attempted using Drupal 8's configuration synchronization but I receive the following message

```
The staged configuration cannot be imported, 
because it originates from a different site than this site. 
You can only synchronize configuration 
between cloned instances of this site.
```

I've attempted using the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module. But I don't see an option for exporting and importing to separate sites.

I've also looked at a similar question here [Sync content between two Drupal sites](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32941/sync-content-between-two-drupal-sites)
However that applies to Drupal 7.

Is there a way to import and export nodes, site settings, and configurations such as menu items and what modules are turned on or off from one site to another?

UPDATE: I've discovered that I might be able to use configuration synchronization if I get the UUIDs to match, but I'm having trouble running drush on my multisite. Is there a way to manually change the UUID in the database?

Answer (score 0):

See this question and answers on why what you want to do is not possible at the moment.

[How to add the configuration changes from a website to another website?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177326/how-to-add-the-configuration-changes-from-a-website-to-another-website?rq=1)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.