# How can I fix site UUID does not match error during config import?

Tags: 8, drush, migrations, configuration

I'm getting this error below whenever I try executing the commands `drush config-import staging` on the CLI. I'm basically in the process of migrating a drupal 7 DB to Drupal 8 and currently following this guide since I'm still new with migration.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z2FH0efd_g

---

```
Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors validating the config synchronization. in         [error]
Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate() (line 728 of
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal-eight-iom/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php).
The import failed due for the following reasons:                                                                [error]
Site UUID in source storage does not match the target storage.
Entities exist of type <em class="placeholder">Shortcut link</em> and <em class="placeholder">Shortcut set</em>
<em class="placeholder">Default</em>. These entities need to be deleted before importing.
The core.extension configuration does not exist.
Can not uninstall the Configuration module as part of a configuration synchronization through the user
interface.
```

---

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'drupal-eight-iom',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);

$databases['upgrade']['default'] = array (
    'database' => 'drupal-seven-iom',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '3306',
    'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
  );


$settings['install_profile'] = 'standard';
$config_directories['staging'] = 'sites/default/config';
$config_directories['sync'] = 'sites/default/files/config_zB_DnNUK68i5Owp5a8FzTiClQfp3d3jrwcy0_HuS1hNCGv9Y_Iva2Ahm8LCH-P0j0M2jwmQAsA/sync';
```

Answer (score 1):

> Site UUID in source storage does not match the target storage.

Make sure you've `system.site.yml` on your staging site, see: [Site UUID in source storage does not match the target storage](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/204859/1908).

To check the current UUID, run:

```
drush config-get "system.site" uuid
```

to change it, run:

```
drush config-set "system.site" uuid "xyz"
```

See: [How can I import the configuration on a different site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/150481/1908)

> Entities exist of type *Shortcut link* and *Shortcut set* *Default*. These entities need to be deleted before importing.

Try removing these entities manually before the import as it says.

> The `core.extension` configuration does not exist.

Make sure you've `core.extension.yml` file in your config folder, otherwise generate one via `config-export`.

> Can not uninstall the Configuration module as part of a configuration synchronization through the user interface.

Most likely it's related to the missing `core.extension.yml`.

---

Few hints:

- You can also try to import the config using [Drupal Console](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console) using [`config:import`](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/config-import.html).
- For debugging purposes, try to import one file at a time. See: [Import a single yml configuration file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/221592/1908). For example:

  ```
  drupal config:import:single --directory=$PWD/config/sync --file=file.yml
  ```
- If you're using different config dirs per environment, consider using [Config Split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split).