# How do I import configuration without getting these errors?

Tags: 8, importing-exporting

I am using `drush cim` and `drush cex` for importing and exporting the  configuration between environments.

At this moment, local and develop are working OK, but I am getting an error on stage.

This is the error.

> The import failed due to the following reasons:
>   This config does not have system.site, rejected
>   UUID source site does not match current site.
>
> Config core.extension does not exists.

But actually both of them exists. I have already ran `drupal config.override` and set the UUID on system.site, but I am still getting those errors.

I have also tried `drush cr`.

The system site has the same UUID as local. It's the same file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Site UUID in source storage does not match the target storage](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204859/site-uuid-in-source-storage-does-not-match-the-target-storage)

Comment: I have done already but still getting that error.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150481/how-can-i-import-the-configuration-on-a-different-site/190282#190282

Comment: also done, the uuid is the same...not sure if its a cache issue, i have ran drush cr as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import the configuration on a different site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150481/how-can-i-import-the-configuration-on-a-different-site)

Comment: already done :(

Comment: Is there already content on stage you need to preserve? If no, reinstall, and then set the site UUID.

Comment: not working yet. i cant do it, everything is via git.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue using config suite module: install this module and it will assign the uuid for those enviroments so you don't need to worry to set up manually.

Comment: But how exactly?

Comment: Install module and it will assign the uuid for those enviroments so you dont need to worry to set up manually.