# Why will drupal not recognize my configuration?

Tags: 8, drush, configuration

I am trying to import configuration from one site to another.  I have copied the directory full of config files from an older site to my new site.  When I try to run Drush cim, the files all show up as they will be created.  However, after answering yes to the prompt I get

```
This import is empty and if applied would delete all of your configuration, so has been rejected. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate() (line 756 of
/home/vagrant/code/indigo-signs-pantheon/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php).
The import failed due for the following reasons:                                                                                                                                                                                   [error]
This import is empty and if applied would delete all of your configuration, so has been rejected
```

I found [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150481/how-can-i-import-the-configuration-on-a-different-site/217126#:%7E:text=The%20staged%20configuration%20cannot%20be,cloned%20instances%20of%20this%20site.) and tried changing the UUID like suggested, but it didnt change anything I still get the same error.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This import is empty

This error might occurs when the config directory is not configured in the settings.php.

Check for the config directory settings in new site. It will mostly have a different directory configured.

Change to the same folder path as in the old site.

Comment: This was it.  When i copied my directory to the new site i copied the whole directory into the new location not contents of the directory into the new location