# Webform export to other website or pc

Tags: webforms, importing-exporting

I have tested a webform module on my localhost and because I have created a fully-functional and complex form (using conditional logic, dropdown menus, radio buttons, etc.) I don't want to loose, I want to export this form to a completely different computer or website via USB stick (for example).

Is there a way I can export my webform with all the settings I have created, without loosing anything ?

I have tried to export **single item** via `Home >> Administration >> Configuration >> Development >> Synchronize` and then import those data to other computer, but did not suceeded.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal in D8 added UUID to identify & differentiate one Drupal from another and was also added so people don't accidentally add config to the wrong site.

So you already got an export from site A.

Now on site B do an export for an existing webform, like Contact (which was created by default when you installed webform) and copy its UUID value.

[image]

Now use this UUID and replace site A's export UUID with it.

#### Important

If this is a one time thing, the above is alright. But if you're going to constantly export config from site A to site B multiple times, then perhaps chaging site's B UUID to A's (so they are identical) is the better solution, see [How can I import the configuration on a different site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150481/how-can-i-import-the-configuration-on-a-different-site)