# How can I import staged configuration?

Tags: drush, configuration, 10

I'm trying to import configuration with `drush cim`. I'm getting

```
Rename operation for simple configuration. Existing configuration system.site and staged configuration domain.config.xxx.system.site.
```

I looked at config/sync and there are a bunch of domain.config.xxx.system.site files. I looked at settings.php and there's no mention of the domain keyword. I was referred [https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150481/how-can-i-import-the-configuration-on-a-different-site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/150481/17632) but that's a different issue. Search engines don't have information on this specific issue. How can I import these?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that config was created using the [Domain module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain), or more accurately its submodule, Domain Config.

To import it without changing the files, you'll need to install and configure the module so it has the same settings as the site it was exported from, at least in terms of the domain settings.

Another approach might simply be to remove `domain.config.xxx` from the start of each file name. looking at how the `ConfigDomainOverrider` class works it seems to just be adjusting file names, so it might be that simple.

Comment: Based on your answer, all I have to do is import the relevant yml files, namely domain.settings.yml and domain_config_ui.settings.yml, right?

Comment: Assuming the relevant modules are enabled, that sounds about right